# ViewModel Property Null in Post Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is now fixed. A combination of Ish's suggestion below plus adding calls to @HiddenFor in the view resolved the problem.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application where users can mark a defect as resolved. I want to display a list of potentially related defects, with check-boxes that users can tick to indicate that yes, this is the same defect, and should also be marked as resolved.

So I have a View Model with a property that is a collection, each member of which contains a defect object property and Boolean `IsSameDefect` property. This all works fine in the GET action method and in the view. I can display the related defects and tick the boxes.

The problem arises in the POST action when I want to update the data. At this point the property (the collection of potentially related defects) is null. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to pass this data back to the controller?

Code as requested ...

```
// GET: /DefectResolution/Create
public ActionResult Create(int ciid)
{
    int companyId = User.CompanyID();
    DefectResolutionCreateViewModel drcvm = new DefectResolutionCreateViewModel(ciid, companyId);
    return View(drcvm);
}

// POST: /DefectResolution/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(DefectResolutionCreateViewModel drcvm)
{
    DefectResolutions currentResolution = drcvm.DefectResolution;
    currentResolution.CreatedOn = System.DateTime.Now;
    currentResolution.UserID = User.UserID();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unitOfWork.DefectResolutionRepository.Insert(currentResolution);

        if (currentResolution.ResolutionStatusID == 2)
        {
            //code breaks here as drcvm.RelatedUnresolvedDefects is null
            foreach (var relatedDefect in drcvm.RelatedUnresolvedDefects)
            {
                if (relatedDefect.IsSameDefect)
                {
                    DefectResolutions relatedResolution = new DefectResolutions();
                    relatedResolution.ChecklistID = relatedDefect.RelatedChecklist.ChecklistID;
                    relatedResolution.CreatedOn = System.DateTime.Now;
                    relatedResolution.ResolutionNote = currentResolution.ResolutionNote;
                    relatedResolution.ResolutionStatusID = currentResolution.ResolutionStatusID;
                    relatedResolution.UserID = User.UserID();
                }
            }
        }

        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ciid = currentResolution.ChecklistID });
    }
    return View(drcvm);
}
```

In the view ...

```
@model Blah.ViewModels.DefectResolution.DefectResolutionCreateViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Defect Resolution";
    var relatedDefects = Model.RelatedUnresolvedDefects;
}
```

... and later in the view ...

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < relatedDefects.Count(); i++ )
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(x => relatedDefects[i].IsSameDefect)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I followed Ish's suggestion below, and modified the code to refer to Model.RelatedUnresolvedDefects directly instead of using a variable as I had been doing. This does get me a bit further. The view model's RelatedUnresolvedDefects  property is no longer null. But only RelatedUnresolvedDefects.IsSameDefect has a value. RelatedUnresolvedDefects.RelatedChecklist is null. Here's the controller code again showing where it now breaks ...

```
// POST: /DefectResolution/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(DefectResolutionCreateViewModel drcvm)
{
    DefectResolutions currentResolution = drcvm.DefectResolution;
    currentResolution.CreatedOn = System.DateTime.Now;
    currentResolution.UserID = User.UserID();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        unitOfWork.DefectResolutionRepository.Insert(currentResolution);

        if (currentResolution.ResolutionStatusID == 2)
        {
            //prior to change, code used to break here
            foreach (var relatedDefect in drcvm.RelatedUnresolvedDefects)
            {
                if (relatedDefect.IsSameDefect)
                {
                    DefectResolutions relatedResolution = new DefectResolutions();

                    //code now breaks here because relatedDefect.RelatedChecklist is null
                    relatedResolution.ChecklistID = relatedDefect.RelatedChecklist.ChecklistID;
                    relatedResolution.CreatedOn = System.DateTime.Now;
                    relatedResolution.ResolutionNote = currentResolution.ResolutionNote;
                    relatedResolution.ResolutionStatusID = currentResolution.ResolutionStatusID;
                    relatedResolution.UserID = User.UserID();
                }
            }
        }

        unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { ciid = currentResolution.ChecklistID });
    }
    return View(drcvm);
}
```

Comment: Please post some code. Only then we can help you with where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your code.I suggest you to use `for` loop instead of `foreach` while rendering the defects in View (.cshtml).

Editing Answer based on your code.
Following statement in the view creating problem

```
 var relatedDefects = Model.RelatedUnresolvedDefects;
```

You should directly iterate over the `Model.RelatedUnresolvedDefects` property in the loop.

```
             @for (int i = 0; i < Model.RelatedUnresolvedDefects.Count(); i++ )
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.RelatedUnresolvedDefects[i].IsSameDefect)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
```

Comment: I had to add a bunch of @Html.HiddenFor calls to the view, but that in combination with Ish's suggestion above resolved the problem, thanks!