# On Post action method the List<className> and SelectList properties of a ViewModel are always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on this official [ASP.NET tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search.html). I've extended the tutorial a bit to include the POST action method Index(...) as well. But When I post the form I get the `NullReferenceException` at the line `foreach (var item in model.movies)...` of the controller below. When I place a breakpoint at this line and hover over the word `model` the `Intellisense` shows the two properties `List<movie>` and `SelectList genre` of the ViewModel to be null and only the third property `movieGenre` is showing (that is a SelectedValue from the dropdown).

**Note**: The issue seems to be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840667/1232087) but as you can see I'm following the solution described there.

**Models**:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class MovieGenreViewModel
{
    public List<Movie> movies;
    public SelectList genres;
    public string movieGenre { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(MovieGenreViewModel model, string Filter, string movieGenre, string searchString)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter))
    {
        IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in _context.Movie
                                        orderby m.Genre
                                        select m.Genre;

        var movies = from m in _context.Movie
                        select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(movieGenre))
        {
            movies = movies.Where(x => x.Genre == movieGenre);
        }

            var movieGenreVM = new MovieGenreViewModel();
            movieGenreVM.genres = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
            movieGenreVM.movies = await movies.ToListAsync();

            return View(movieGenreVM);
    }
    else if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var item in model.movies)
        {
            //..code to insert/update movie records to database
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return View(model);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View();
}
```

**View**:

```
@model MovieGenreViewModel

<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        <select asp-for="movieGenre" asp-items="Model.genres">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
        <input type="submit" name="Filter" value="Filter" />
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Genre</th>
            ....
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            @for(int i = 0; i< Model.movies.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => Model.movies[i].Genre)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => Model.movies[i].Price)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => Model.movies[i].ReleaseDate</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(r => Model.movies[i].Title)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type = "submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields. Make the collection a property - `public List<Movie> movies { get; set; }` (and it should be `@Html.EditorFor(r => r.movies[i].Genre)` etc)

Comment: Note you have other issues with your code, including that it will throw an exception when you return the view because you have not repopulated the `SelectList`

Comment: And what happens when the user starts to enter a few characters in the `SearchString` input and has also made numerous changes to the textboxes for the collection (how happy do you think they will be when they discover that none of their changes have been saved)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your suggestion worked - thank you. I've made a note of your comments in regard to `SearchString` for my real app. This one was just a trial app for dealing with the issue you helped resolve.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Per your suggestion in another post, I've implemented PRG pattern; and hence `SelectList` gets repopulated. In the POST action I'm calling `return RedirectToAction("myGETAction", new { movieGenre = movieGenre});` where movieGenre on the left is an input parameter of GET action and on the right it's the SelectedValue.

Comment: The last line of the controller code in your question is `return View();` (for when `ModelState` is invalid - in which case you do need to return the view so errors can be corrected, not redirect) but you have not reassigned the `SelectList` so you would get an exception :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Uhmm! `public SelectList genres;` being a property of  model and model not being in ValidState, I do need to repopulate the `SelectList` before `return View();` statement. `